# "[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found"

Tags: android, cordova

I recently uploaded my phonegap build to Google Play and am seeing a `Error initializing Cordova: Class not found` error. It is not correctly displaying my index.html and am unsure what the problem is. It seems like it is not picking up the Cordova plugin. Can anyone with experience troubleshoot me?

My config file in /platforms/android/res/xml/

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.treatfinder" version="2.1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
<plugins>
<plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
</plugins>
<feature name="UniversalAnalytics">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.danielcwilson.plugins.analytics.UniversalAnalyticsPlugin" />
</feature>
<feature name="GoogleAppTracking">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.myhealthteams.plugins.GoogleAppTracking" />
</feature>
<feature name="EmailComposer">
    <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.emailcomposer.EmailComposer" />
</feature>
<feature name="Printer">
    <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer.Printer" />
</feature>
<feature name="KitKatPrinter">
    <param name="android-package" value="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.printer.KitKatPrinter" />
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
<feature name="SQLitePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin" />
</feature>
     <name>TreatFinder</name>
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2174c4" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/MF-Splash-iPad.jpg" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/MF-Splash-iPad-landscape.jpg" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="res/screen/ios/MF-Splash-iPad.jpg" width="1536" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="res/screen/ios/MF-Splash-iPad-landscape@2x.jpg" width="2048" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import CordovaApp-CordovaLib properly.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way I can do this using terminal or edit my files? Not sure why my eclipse build is not working.

Comment: No, this is only the way.